# Writing systems of linear equations

Tags: systems-of-equations

Would anyone be able to help me with the following question? Thank you.

- Point 1: When there is 1 car passing the road, the average speed is
  50km/h.
- Point 2: When there are 5 cars passing the road, the average speed is
  45km/h.
- Point 3: When there are 12 cars passing the road, the average speed
  is 38km/h.

A traffic engineering company decides to model the average speed (shown by u) as a linear function of the number of cars (shown by n). So we want to have

u(n)=α+βn.

Use Point 1, Point 2 and Point 3 information: write a system of linear equations
to calculate α and β using all three points; i.e. we will have three equations with two
unknowns.

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/510476/18398 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/509980/18398