# How would I write this in matrix form?

Tags: matrices

Point 1: When there is 1 car passing the road, the average speed is 50km/h.

Point 2: When there are 5 cars passing the road, the average speed is 45km/h.

Point 3: When there are 12 cars passing the road, the average speed is 38km/h.

How do I write all 3 systems of linear equations this in matrix form? Any help is appreciated.

50 = α + β

45 = α + 5β

38 = α + 12β

Comment: Did you really ask the same question four times?!?!  Also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/509980/91818), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/508663/91818), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/509922/91818).